# Why does the following statement cause a SyntaxErrorException?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to create a table using JDBC but i am getting syntax error at the query .

```
Statement statement = con.createStatement();
String query = "CREATE TABLE accounts (user VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
                                       password VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
                                       dateRegistered date "+
                                      "primary key (user));";

statement.executeUpdate(query);
System.out.println("part 2:DONE !");
```

This is the error :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL, dateRegistered date, pr' at line 1    
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)    
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)    
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)    
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)    
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)    
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:372)    
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)    
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)    
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)    
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)    
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)    
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2531)    
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2489)    
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:848)    
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:742)    
at Test.main(Test.java:26)
```

Comment: Please add the error message and add the DBMS tag

Comment: Add a comma between the last field definition and the PRIMARY KEY definition.

Comment: I added a comma, same error.

Comment: Quick advice, if you have problem with SQL syntax test your query on your database directly before using it in code. Or even better create table using some GUI tool (like HeidiSQL) and see generated SQL code. This will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQL

MySQL does not support VARCHAR2, so replace it with `VARCHAR`

And add a `comma` before primary key.

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE accounts (user VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, dateRegistered date, primary key (user));";
```

Comment: Thank you sir ! That was the problem.

Comment: Whoever has down voted the answer, please add a comment for it.